# Knockout js observableArray is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to update the observable array from the response data. 
I'm sure I've missed something simple, but I can't find out why it doesn't work?

```js
function addWitness() {

  $.post("AddWintess", {
    Witnesses: [{
      LastName: "test1",
      FirstName: "test1",
      MiddleName: "test1"
    }, {
      LastName: "test2",
      FirstName: "test2",
      MiddleName: "test2"
    }]
  }, function(data) {
    my.viewModel.allItems = ko.observableArray(data.Witnesses);
  });
}
var my = {
  viewModel: new WitnessesModel()
}

function WitnessesModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.allItems = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.test = ko.computed(function() {
    var result = "";
    self.allItems().forEach(function(item) {
      result += item + "; ";
    });
  });
}
ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: allItems">
  <li data-bind="text: FirstName"></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="+" onclick="addWitness()" />
```

I've set the breakpoints in the test function, but it's not getting fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line `my.viewModel.allItems(data.Witnesses);` instead of

`my.viewModel.allItems = ko.observableArray(data.Witnesses);`